# Is there any way to retrieve added date of a Song (Medialibrary)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, msdn

I want to make a list of recently added Songs in Windowsphone 8. 
Is there any way to get the properties of a song such as "last edited date" etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such property available:
[Song Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx)